# How to configure an OSGi service using descriptor file in Sling?

Tags: osgi, sling

I want to configure the Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service using a text file. I created a file under `jcr_root/apps/sling/config` and this file is called org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl.json.

This is the content of the file:

```
{
    "jcr:primaryType":"sling:OsgiConfig",
    "user.mapping" : "artifact.name=systemUserName"
}
```

The file is created in the JCR and the properties are correctly resolved, but the service is not being configured. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, to configure a service in Sling, the descriptor file has to be stored under`jcr_root/apps/sling/install` directory.

More about Sling Installer can be found [here](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/jcr-installer-provider.html).

Comment: This is partially correct. The Apache Sling JCR Installer is configurable, see: http://localhost:8080/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr.impl.JcrInstaller. Out of the box, you can store your OSGi configs in either `install` or `config` which can be up to 4 levels deep. The standard practice would be to use a `config` folder rather than `install` such as `/apps/<project name>/config`. From there, you can get into run mode specifications such as `config.prod.chicago` or `config.qa`.